# Java - Inheritance -Generics

Tags: java

I have a couple of POJO classes as below

```
//pojo
public class Shipment { }

//pojo
public class DigitalShipment extends Shipment { }
```

A class `PaymentA` as below

```
public class PaymentA extends Payment<Shipment> {
    
    public void execute(Shipment shipment) {
    
    // some business logic.
    }

    private void methodA() {
    }
    
    private void methodB() {
    }

    private void methodC() {
    }

}
```

Now I need to write another class `PaymentB`, but what I found is that the logic that I have to write here is almost similar to the `PaymentA` class. the only difference is in `PaymentA` it accepts `Shipment` while in `PaymentB` it accepts `DigitalShipment`.

Is there a way to avoid this duplicate code?. If I would go ahead and write this class, I do not like to duplicate private methods to this class as well.

One option I have is to create a new class, helper, and push these private methods there but most of the logic in execute method will also be duplicate across all classes, so I am trying to think if there is a better way to achieve this?

```
public class PaymentB extends Payment<DigitalShipment> {

    public void execute(DigitalShipment shipment) {

    // Almost same business logic 
    }

    private void methodA() {
    // copy of paymentA class methodA
    }
    
    private void methodB() {
    // copy of paymentA class methodB
    }

    private void methodC() {
    // copy of paymentA class methodC

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify the part that is different. Does `execute` method of `PaymentB` access methods/fields specific to `DigitalShipment`? If no, I don't see a need for `PaymentB` at all.

Comment: the problem is that the classes are part of the workflow, in one flow we have reference to the  shipment object while in other flow it has access to DigitalShipment.

Comment: It doesn’t seem right that Payment is generic and _still_ you need to subclass it